# Create forms in Joomla custom html module for multiple tables

Tags: joomla-3.x, form-fields-types, custom-field, jtable

I would like to add a form that takes input for two tables.
One table with single row insert to 1st table, and the other one, with multiple rows insert to 2nd table at the same time.

I have read about **Custom form fields** in Joomla but I am confused regarding how to add them into a module.
At the end of the form there should be a submit button which would validate and take the values to the database.

I have checked the article on Joomla.org but am not getting the right way to include the fields into the module

https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type
Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Could you please share the code you've tried?

Comment: I tried using sourcerer and insert the code into custom html module but it didnt work out.
 <field name="matchID" type="editor" class="inputbox" 

label="" description="table_name" 

filter="ContentHelper::filterText" buttons="true" />
**between the {source} tags** and with a submit button

Comment: You're trying to insert XML code using sourcerer?

Comment: Yes I didnt know the exact way to proceed

Comment: @Lodder Can you please suggest what is the correct method to do it ?

Comment: I would suggest you develop a small module or component. Have a look through the Joomla documentation. I would refrain from doing this through Sourcerer

Comment: @Lodder I am new to this Joomla Dev. for creating a custom form module.Please suggest some resources to start off with .

Comment: You could use my [Module Generator](http://joomjunk.co.uk/extras-page/module-generator.html) that I've developed if you want. Please note that this will generate the module files/structure allowing you to install it. You will of course have to add your own code to the files, but I still suggest you also check the Joomla documentation to see how modules work. You can always post another question if you run into a specific coding issue ;)

Comment: Great resource to start off with my first module ! How to add the front end form code in the Module Generator Extension !

Comment: You don't do this in the Module Generator. As mentioned before, this simply generates the files/structure required to build your module. You will need to open the files in your text editor and add the code yourself

Comment: Or use this extension http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/news-display/tables-a-lists/droptables

Comment: @webdevelopment Those are input fields for the rows in the database.